# Riverpod Stream Provider, its better to watch or read a stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

In the documentation:

> Whenever possible, prefer using ref.watch over ref.read or ref.listen to implement a feature.
>
> By relying on ref.watch, your application becomes both reactive and declarative, which makes it more maintainable.

Lets say I have a `StreamProvider` listen to `authStateChanges()` in firebase:

```
class AuthRepo {
......
Stream<User> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((fUser){
     final user = fUser == null ? User.empty : fUser.toUser;
     _cache.write(key: user.id, value: user);
     return user;
    });
  }
.......
}
```

and create a provider to that class:

```
final authRepoProvider  = Provider((ref){
  return AuthRepo();
});

final authStateProvider = StreamProvider((ref){
  final result_1 = ref.read(authRepoProvider).user;
  final result_2 = ref.watch(authRepoProvider).user;

});
```

Both results return `Stream<User>`. So when using `ref.read`, the stream itself never changes right? maybe I am wrong but if I use `ref.watch` it means I `stream` to another `stream<User>`. I read the documentation several times and am still confused about how to approach this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [red flag in the docs](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#can-i-read-a-provider-without-listening-to-it) that says:

> **DON'T CALL [READ](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Ref/read.html) INSIDE THE BODY OF A PROVIDER**
>
> ```
> final myProvider = Provider((ref) {
>   // Bad practice to call `read` here
>   final value = ref.read(anotherProvider);
> });
> ```
>
> If you used [read](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Ref/read.html) as an attempt to avoid unwanted rebuilds of your object, refer to [My provider updates too often, what can I do?](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers#my-provider-updates-too-often-what-can-i-do)

This includes the other providers like `StreamProvider`. So, just use the safer `ref.watch`.

> If possible, avoid using read and prefer watch, which is generally safer to use.